# Where to set require once include in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, payment-gateway, braintree

My requirement is to include the braintree into my laravel application. The first step I have copied the whole sdk into the my laravel app folder and the folder is named `braintree-php`. Next I go into my `C:\xampp\htdocs\cserver\resources\views\layouts` and in my `app.blade.php` below is part of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@section('includebt')

@show
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>My system @yield ('role-heading')</title>
```

Then I have my actual blade page where I extend from the above app layout.This is just part of the codes there is more in detail below but my focus is on the library include.

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('includebt')
include(app_path().'/braintree-php/lib/Braintree.php');
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('**');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('***');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('***');

@endsection
```

I am getting this error `Class 'Braintree\ClientToken' not found (View:`

Comment: Are you asking about brain tree service provider ?

Comment: No I am asking how to include in laravel like you have in php require_once("../braintree-php/lib/Braintree.php");

Comment: but why you want it to include in view and no through composer ??? and extend and use through controller ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I am sorry very new to this? So when you say through composer meaning? How to do that and how to extend use through controller?

Comment: can you send me a link of braintree where you are taking reference from ? may be you are going with wrong reference .

Comment: Here is the link https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php

Comment: I use the download method as I am not familiar with the composer method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133166/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-user5313398).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it through composer like

open composer.json file
there only one requre
make it

```
"require": { 
"laravel/framework": "5.0.*", 
"illuminate/html": "^5.0", 
"braintree/braintree_php" : "3.20.0" 
},
```

and use composer update from artisian

[image: composer update]

after that you need to setup your environment and generate client token and follow [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php)  . you may also think to go [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=braintree%20laravel%205) .